# How to evaluate every element of a list with Sympy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have a list A below and I want to print the evaluated version where theta = 90°.

```
import sympy as sp 

theta = sp.symbols('theta')

A = [sp.cos(theta), sp.sin(theta),0,0]
```

```
theta_val = sp.pi / 2
A_evaluated = [A.subs([theta, theta_val])]

print(A_evaluated)
```

I got "AttributeError: list object has no attribute subs". Any idea on how to revise this?

Comment: Do you need to call `subs` on each element of the list? A list comprehension can help you in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sympy as sp 

theta = sp.symbols('theta')

A = [sp.cos(theta), sp.sin(theta),0,0]

theta_val = sp.pi / 2

[x.subs([(theta,theta_val)]) for x in A if type(x)!= int]
```

or

```
[x.subs([(theta,theta_val)]) for x in A if not isinstance(x, int)]
```

You need to `type(int)!= int` else you will get  `'int' object has no attribute 'subs'` for `0,0`.

```
#output
[0, 1]
```

Comment: That will be `type(x)!= int` in the last sentence.